# Accessing HTML Table Cell Data

Tags: javascript

I need to access to the data of a html cell,but before that ,I need to store the id of my  array (details[i].id) in a cell. I tried with a hidden, but I get an empty cell when I show the table and that's not what I want, what I want is something like the DataKeyNames in ASP.net, that gives us the chance to store the id without necessarily showing it.

This is the code I use to show my array (details) in a html table:

```
function showTable()
{
    if (details.length>0){
        for (var i=0; i<details.length;i++)
        {
            var tbl = document.getElementById('myTable');

            var newRow = tbl.insertRow(tbl.rows.length);

            var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
            cell1.textAlign='center';
            cell1.innerHTML=details[i].price;

            var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
            cell2.textAlign='center';
            cell2.innerHTML=details[i].description;

            var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
            cell3.textAlign='center';
            cell3.innerHTML='<a href="#"><img src="images/delete.png" width="14" height="14" alt="Delete" onclick="removeDetail(this)"/></a>'

        }



    }
}
```

And finally in the **removeDetail** function is where I need to get the cell value, assuming I somehow put the id there.

```
function removeDetail(r)
{
    var node = r.parentNode;
    while( node && node.tagName !== 'TR' ) {
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    var i=node.rowIndex;

    document.getElementById('myTable').deleteRow(i);

    //here's where I need to get the id and, if posible the other values ( price, description) too.



}
```

Hope you can help me out.

Comment: Comment will not bump your question, you can edit to bump it back to the top but don't do that so fast. Wait at least half day before bumping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First step:** store the index as custom attribute of your element:

```
cell3.innerHTML='<a href="#"><img src="images/delete.png" width="14" height="14" alt="Delete" onclick="removeDetail(this)" details_index="' + i + '" /></a>'
```

**Second step:** store the row as part of the global array:

```
details[i].row = newRow;
```

**Final step:** In the removeDetail function read the index and you have all you need:

```
function removeDetail(r)
{
    var item = details[parseInt(r.getAttribute("details_index"), 10)];
    item.row.style.display = "none";
    alert("price: " + item.price + ", description: " + item.description);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
function checkSequence()

{

  var oTable = document.getElementById('tableID');
  var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;
  var count=0;

  for (i = 0; i&lt;rowLength-1; i++){
    var cellVal = document.getElementById('tableID:'+i).value;
  }

}
```